# What is the proper way to read in data from SQLite everytime the app is reopened

Tags: swift, sqlite

I'm at the start of developing an app which takes users' inputs, stores them in a SQLite database (in stead of using Core Data since I'm more familiar with SQL and C language and Core Data is kind of error proning from what I've heard), and then shows them on the screen. However, I assume that everytime when I clear the cache and reopen the app, I have to somehow read data from SQLite database right?

So should we use `select * from` query to select every row in the SQLite database, and then show them on the screen. Or is there some other better way to do it?

I've searched for **preloading data from SQLite database in SwiftUI**, most researches are for **Core Data** instead of directly using **SQLite** and using **Json** format, which is probably not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm a little confused because your SQLite database should be in a file and not stored in memory. I think what you should try to do is find a tutorial on first saving the SQLite database. I think what I used to do have one file manage database stuff (e.g. inserts, updates, and select) like an ORM. That way, by having some class create a pointer every time you instantiate, you should be able to easily access your SQLite file. But baby steps: make sure your SQLite file is saved in a location first. Find a tutorial for that.

Comment: I agree with @acw you should look at some tutorials I think you are mixing terms. CoreData supports SQLLite as a store type. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html by not using CoreData you will have to create all the persistence methods and all the listening features on your own. `select * from` is one way of retrieving (inefficient since it is carrying everything all the time) but you also likely need to setup a way to retrieve individual records.

Comment: @acw  I'm actually following the tutorial right now and I just learned the swift implementation of SQLite basic insertion, deletion, update, create a database, and so on. What I mean is, after finishing all of this, I assume we can initiate a DB pointer when the program starts and starts inserting and reading data from the SQLite DB. My question is that after reopening the app, should I read all data from the SQLite database using something like ```select * from``` or is there a better way to start off my app by first retrieving all information that already exists in my database.

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for your suggestions. I'm actually following the tutorial right now and I just learned the swift implementation of SQLite basic insertion, deletion, update, create a database, and so on. From what I learned in some videos, those operations are enough for loading an app from the information that I've already had in the database. I'm trying to look for a better way to load my app instead of using the my swift wrapper function which wraps ```select * from``` because like you said, ```select * from``` is inefficient.

Comment: Awesome basic CRUD is enough to start but make sure that whatever you use implements the listening/observing changes of the database elements. SwiftUI is heavily dependent on observing changes so it knows when to refresh the `View`. The reason most of the tutorials reference CoreData is because it comes with this built-in and SwiftUI has wrappers that connect everything seamlessly.

Comment: Yes the moment your program starts, you can create a connection to your DB. Regarding efficiency, I wouldn't worry too much about it unless it's a lot and blocking (i.e. synchronous). You can use something like DispatchGroup to execute everything in a background task and then use Combine to send data to a currently loaded ViewController, but perhaps we can take UITableViewController as an example (in terms of efficiency). You can do something with OFFSET key word with SQL when it comes to loading data into a table.

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks. My database is just for loading data from database if a user restarts his/her app. So it is only used at the very beginning when app gets opened. So do you know any other way to retrieve all the information using SQLite Database language instead of simple ```select * from``` ?

Comment: @acw thanks！！！！！That was really helpful. So do you think it's more convenient to use CoreData method in my case ? or just some basic CRUD is fiine. I used simple CRUD because I've heard CoreData method is error proning sometimes.

Comment: Again, I wouldn't worry so much about the technology you're using; just use what's more comfortable with. It seems like you're loading a lot of data, so you should be thinking about what UI components you're going to be using and how to efficiently recycle that data. In the case of a UITableView, some rows may disappear due to memory. That means you need to implement the proper constructors to make sure the table view can grab data at a certain index. So again, think in terms of comfort and also your UI configuration. If you're comfortable with SQLite, use that. There are plenty of wrappers.